# Missing My namespace in Roslyn VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

When I try to compile and emit the following VB.NET code using Roslyn,

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName)

    End Sub
End Module
```

I get the following error

```
error BC30451: 'My' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

MSDN [mentions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233781.aspx) that My namespace is added by the compiler depending on value of the _MYTYPE conditional-compilation constant.

In Roslyn all that My magic is not available anymore, is it?

My code:

```
Imports Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
Imports Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices

Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Dim code = "Module Module1" + Environment.NewLine +
                       "Sub Main()" + Environment.NewLine +
                           "System.Console.WriteLine(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName)" + Environment.NewLine +
                       "End Sub" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "End Module"

        Dim tree = VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText(code)

        Dim compilation = VisualBasicCompilation.Create("test").
            AddSyntaxTrees(tree).
            AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(Object).Assembly.Location)).
            AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(StandardModuleAttribute).Assembly.Location))

        Dim emitResult = compilation.Emit("test.exe")
        If Not emitResult.Success Then
            Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, emitResult.Diagnostics))
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: What references did you add?

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson mscorlib and Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: I believe the My.Application stuff is specific to Winforms and WPF, so you'd have to have some references from there.

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson Exactly the same code compiles and works OK as part of a VB.NET Console Application project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]? [It seems to work fine for me.](https://gist.github.com/svick/3258268ac8c34c7e92ac)

Comment: @svick [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e07b9c36ac0fbadaf72) you are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what's going on correctly, the `My` namespace is added by automatically including the file [`VbMyTemplateText.vb`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/a4e375b95953e471660e9686a46893c97db70b0e/src/Compilers/VisualBasic/Portable/Symbols/EmbeddedSymbols/VbMyTemplateText.vb) into each compilation. And to make it actually generate something, [the preprocessor symbol `_MYTYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233781.aspx) has to be set correctly (in the case of a console application to `"Console"`).

To make this work, you also need to reference `System.dll`, but after that everything works fine:

```
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler
Imports Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
Imports Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim code = "Module Module1" + Environment.NewLine +
                       "Sub Main()" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "System.Console.WriteLine(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName)" + Environment.NewLine +
                       "End Sub" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "End Module"

        Dim tree = VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText(code)

        Dim compilation = VisualBasicCompilation.Create("test").
            AddSyntaxTrees(tree).
            AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(Object).Assembly.Location)). ' mscorlib
            AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(GeneratedCodeAttribute).Assembly.Location)). ' System
            AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(GetType(StandardModuleAttribute).Assembly.Location)). ' Microsoft.VisualBasic
            WithOptions(New VisualBasicCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication).WithParseOptions(
                VisualBasicParseOptions.Default.WithPreprocessorSymbols(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("_MYTYPE", "Console"))))

        Dim emitResult = compilation.Emit("test.exe")
        If Not emitResult.Success Then
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, emitResult.Diagnostics))
        End If

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks! The only sad thing here is that you still have to bother with the _MYTYPE value.